# How to change language code in URL

Tags: link-manager

We have a multi language site with `English` and `Thai` and I need to change the default language code in URL for the Thai pages.

eg: `mysite.com/th-th/about` should become `mysite.com/th/about`

My code works though, but I have 2 questions.

1. Is this the right/sitecore way to do it
2. I have replaced the default linkmanager for now. But ours is a multi-site instance. Is there another way to add the Link manager provider, just for a particular site, like from a patch file.

**web.config**

```
//replaced the existing property with custom
 <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
   <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="MySite.Foundation.Common.Utilities.SitecoreExtensions+MySiteLinkProvider, MySite.Foundation.Common" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
    <!--<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />-->        
 </providers>
</linkManager>
```

**custom.config:**

```
<pipelines>
 <httpRequestBegin>
  <processor type="MySite.Foundation.Common.Utilities.SitecoreExtensions+MySiteHttpRequestProcessor, MySite.Foundation.Common" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </httpRequestBegin>
</pipelines>
```

**code:**

```
public class MySiteLinkProvider : LinkProvider 
{
  public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
  {
    string returnUrl = base.GetItemUrl(item, options);

    if (Context.Site.Name.ToLower() == "mysite")
    {
      try
      {
        Language currentLanguage = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Context.Database).Where(x => x.Name == item.Language.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentLanguage != null)
        {
          options.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always;
          options.LanguageLocation = LanguageLocation.FilePath;
          ID languageId = LanguageManager.GetLanguageItemId(item.Language, item.Database);
          var languageItem = item.Database.GetItem(languageId);
          var regionName = item.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower() ?? "";
          returnUrl = base.GetItemUrl(item, options).ToLower().ReplaceFirst(item.Language.Name.ToLower(), regionName);
         }
         else
         {
           string defaultLanguageName = Sitecore.Context.Site.Language.ToLower();
           Language defaultLanguage = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Context.Database).Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == defaultLanguageName).FirstOrDefault();

           if (defaultLanguage != null)
           {
             returnUrl = base.GetItemUrl(item, options).ToLower().ReplaceFirst(item.Language.Name.ToLower(), defaultLanguage.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower());
           }
           else
           {
             returnUrl = base.GetItemUrl(item, options).ToLower().ReplaceFirst(item.Language.Name.ToLower(), defaultLanguageName);
           }
          }
         }
         catch (System.Exception ex)
         {
         }
        }

       return returnUrl;
      }
    }

    public class MySiteHttpRequestProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
      public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
      {
        if (Context.Site.Name.ToLower() == "mysite")
        {
          Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
          string contextLanguageName = Context.Language.Name.ToLower();
          string languageCode = Context.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower();

          if (contextLanguageName != languageCode)
          {
            //if url has th-th, then context language will be th-th. In such case, redirect to the same url but with language code
            //eg: if url is /th-th/home, redirect to /th/home
            string url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Context.Item).ToLower().Replace(contextLanguageName, languageCode);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, false);
           }
           else
           {
             //get the correct language and set it to context and the item.
             Language contextLanguage = Context.Language;
             Language sitecoreLanguage = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Context.Database).Where(x => x.Name == contextLanguageName).FirstOrDefault();
             sitecoreLanguage = sitecoreLanguage ?? LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Context.Database).Where(x => x.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == contextLanguageName).FirstOrDefault();

             if (sitecoreLanguage != null)
             {
               Context.SetLanguage(sitecoreLanguage, true);
               Context.Item = ItemManager.GetItem(args.Url.ItemPath.ReplaceFirst("/" + languageCode, ""), sitecoreLanguage, Version.Latest, Context.Database);
             }
            }
           }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change your language (in system) to "th" instead of "th-th"? That would fix your issue as well without custom code..

Comment: We did try that with no effect. Also, I read that renaming a language works well if it is a fresh project and there are no thai versions. But versions are already created now.

Comment: Stephen Pope has answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129168/rename-language-after-item-is-created   If I were you, I would skip the "dirty" parts in his answer and use the actual update of the language of your items

Answer (score 6):

Best way to do this is by using physicalFolder/virtualFolder parameters in site definitions.

**step 1**: Add seperate site definitions before "website" site definition as follows

```
    <site name="th-site" patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
     virtualFolder="/th" physicalFolder="/th" rootPath="/sitecore/content" 
     startItem="/Home" hostName="mysite.com"  database="web" language="th-th" 
     inherits="website" /> 

    <site name="en-site" patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
     virtualFolder="/en" physicalFolder="/en" rootPath="/sitecore/content" 
     startItem="/Home" hostName="mysite.com"  database="web" language="en" 
     inherits="website" />
```

NOTE: Main things to note is **physicalFolder** & **virtualFolder** settings in the site definition.

**step 2**: In the default link manager, set "languageEmbedding" property to "never".

**UPDATE**:
**step 3**: Set the Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage setting to false
https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.com/2014/01/striplanguage-processor-in-pipeline.html

That's it.

Comment: @scFootsteps. I followed the example and created those two definitions before the default in sitedefiniton.config, but it did not work. When user browses /th-th/home, itsn;t redirecting to /th/home. And when I manually browse /th/home, the content for thai version doesn't load or is empty.

Comment: its not handling redirects. You have to handle redirections from other way/module. regarding empty page when browse /th/home, is your home url is /th or /th/home ? because starting item is determine by rootPath + startItem. So, in the definition i have given, when you browse /th/ , you should see the /sitecore/content/home item. Also, have you setup languages for the site definitions. can you post your site definitions by running the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx ??

Comment: also, have you setup both virtualFolder & physicalFolder to /th ??

Comment: @Qwerty I have added a step 3 which needs to tell to sitecore not to strip /th when try to resolve site.